# Meteor subscription inside setState

Tags: javascript, jquery, mongodb, meteor

I was able to write subscription in meteor and it is working fine. now i need to set state inside the Meteor getMeteorData() method. here is my implemented working method

```
getMeteorData() {
    Meteor.subscribe('Posts', Meteor.userId());
    return {
      Posts: Posts.find({}, {
        sort: {
          createdAt: -1
        }
      }).fetch(),
    };
  }
```

also i want it to be something like this. mean i want to set the state inside function. but when i code like below it return exception on the console.

```
getMeteorData() {
    Meteor.subscribe('Posts', Meteor.userId());
      let medias = [];
      Posts.map(post => {
        post.images.map(image => {
          medias.push({image: image, post: post})
        })
      });
    this.setState({medias: medias});
    return {
      Posts: Posts.find({}, {
        sort: {
          createdAt: -1
        }
      }).fetch(),
    };
  }
```

below is the snap of error [error snap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mo4XC.png)